# Meaning of the joke about the fish and the dam

Tags: humor, jokes, puns

There is the [joke.](http://www.funtoosh.com/jokes/personality/245)

> -What did the fish say when he ran into the wall?
>
> -Dam.

Could someone explain it to me, please?

As far as I can tell the joke is all about the intended pun: the `dam` sounds similar to `damn`. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because explaining jokes is off-topic. Use Yahoo answers or reddit for that.

Comment: `Jokes that do not rely on the English language` are off-topic. This joke does rely on the English language. So, I am sorry to tell you but you are wrong. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You understand the joke correctly. It uses the pun as you describe it.